# Linq sorting of entity by custom property via reflection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, reflection

Got `Customer` class which has `Country` property which has string property `Name`.
Also `Customer` implements `IComparable<Country>` like so:

```
public int CompareTo(Country other)
{
    return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
}
```

Now:

```
var custList = new List<Customer>{...};

custList.OrderBy(cust => cust.Country).ToList(); //Sorts as charm.
```

And if try sorting via reflection:

```
var itemProp = typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Country");

custList = c.Customers.ToList()
    .OrderBy(cust => itemProp.GetValue(cust, null)).ToList(); // Fails
```

Throws exception *'At least one object must implement IComparable'*

Please explain why does it fail and how correctly implement sorting of Customer by custom property via reflection. Thanks.

Comment: `PropertyInfo.GetValue` returns an `Object`, not the `Country` that you need. As a result, you end up trying to sort `Object` instances, not `Country` instances, and they're not comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `GetValue` returns `Object` you need to implement the non generic version of `IComparable`.

```
void Main()
{
    var custList = new List<Customer>()
    { 
        new Customer(){ Country = new Country(){ Name = "Sweden" } },
        new Customer(){ Country = new Country(){ Name = "Denmark" } },
    };

    var itemProp = typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Country");

    custList = custList.OrderBy(cust => itemProp.GetValue(cust, null)).ToList();

    custList.Dump();
}

public class Country : IComparable<Country>, IComparable
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int CompareTo(Country other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        var o = other as Country;
        if(o == null)
            return 0; //Or how you want to handle it
        return CompareTo(o);
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Country Country{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I was editing my answer while you posted yours - I think your answer preceded my edits so this should really be marked as the answer.

Comment: Great and thanks to @Matthew Watson and @Magnus. But what if beside `Country` property `Customer` has also `Address` and some other properties of custom classes? Then implementing non generic `IComparable` like so will limit ability to sort by them in reflection.

Comment: @PaulKyrejto If you wanted to sort by a different property, surely you would just pass the appropriate property name to `GetProperty()`?

Comment: Yes, but how about that part: 
`public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        var o = other as Country;
        if(o == null)
            return 0; //Or how you want to handle it
        return CompareTo(o);
    }`

Here we have explicit cast of `object` to `Country`

Comment: @PaulKyrejto Yes but that's in the class implementation, so of course you expect to have access to the class being defined!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the underlying type is correct (i.e. `Country`), you should be able to do it as long as `Country` implements `IComparable`:

Here's a sample console app that works correctly (note that there is no error handling):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Number: IComparable<Number>, IComparable
    {
        public Number(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public readonly int Value;

        public int CompareTo(Number other)
        {
            return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo((Number) obj);
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public Number Number;

        public object Obj
        {
            get { return Number; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Number.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var itemProp = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Obj");

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",
                data().OrderBy(x => itemProp.GetValue(x, null))));
        }

        static IEnumerable<Test> data()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                yield return new Test {Number = new Number(10-i)};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I need some dynamic cast here otherwise why would I use reflection?

Comment: @PaulKyrejto I've updated my answer to `IComparable` instead.